# Magento Category Import Manually Specify ID

Tags: magento, csv, import, categories

I am currently trying to setup an import script that will read from a CSV file a list of categories with ID numbers and what i would like to do is insert the categories into the root category of the default website but with a specific ID so that i can the insert products into categories by ID number.

http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/quick-script-batch-create-magento-categories/

I am currently using the script from the link above and would like to know if anyone can tell me where i insert the setId() code, i have tried it in several places and it just cancels out the parentId so all the categories are created in the root of the system rather than in the root folder for default store.

I have manually set the parentId to the main root folder of the default site so they should all be created in the same place and if i don't set the ID manually it does create them in the correct place so i think the problem is just syntax, the only problem if i don't set the root folder when they are created in the correct place they have dynamic category id's not the required static ones.

Thanks in Advance.
Brad

Answer (score 1):

Just add a third column to your CSV-file:

> 3,subcat,2700

And then add the line with the entity_id to your script.

```
$data['general']['path'] = $line[0];
$data['general']['name'] = $line[1];
$data['general']['entity_id'] = $line[2];
$data['general']['meta_title'] = "";
```

If you want to add the categories into the correct place, you should have a look on parent_id, position, level and path too.

Depending on how much categories you have, I would do it more or less manually, add one more column to the csv and add a line like:

```
$data['general']['path'] = $line[3];
```

Good luck with this

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply but unfortunately this would not be possible as the format of the line must be specific so that the id of the current category is the first field.  Although i don't think this is the problem i have changed the $parentId to a static value and then just reassigned that column to a new variable which i am using to try and set the id of the category.  If i don't specify an ID the category is created in the correct place but as soon as a use the setId() method it defaults to the root of the site so i'm wondering if i'm using the correct method.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem that if I used the `setId()` method (or some other way of setting the ID), my category would never appear nested under its defined parent category/path. I found that I had to do it as a 2-part process: firstly setting the ID and saving the category, then setting the path and re-saving the category.

```
$categoryID = 999;  //Your category ID
$categoryName = 'Category Name';  //Your category name

$parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(888); //Your parent category's ID

//1st save with initial category information (inc. ID)
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->setName($categoryName);
$category->setId($categoryID);
$category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath()); //Shouldn't be needed here
$category->save();

//2nd save with correct path underneath the parent category
$category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath() . '/' . $categoryID);
$category->save();
```

Seems like a bit of a hack, but none of the other suggestions I ever came across helped at all, so I hope this helps someone!